# Redirect based on referral page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, referrer

I have a page site `localhost/abc/page.php`

here I have an .htaccess redirect file, which redirect all requirest to `localhost/xyz/check.php`

check.php checks if user is in record, then send back to `localhost/abc/page.php` otherwise it send to `localhost/abc/no_record_found.php`

problem when it came back from `localhost/xyz/check.php` to `localhost/abc/page.php`  it sends it back in inifite loop, I tried to stop it by referral page condtion like this code but still same problem can someone help?

check.php just contains a code to check if user exists and then header(location:back to page.php)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^localhost/xyz/check.php [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php

RewriteRule (.*) localhost/xyz/check.php [R]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: this is all, do you need to see more?

Comment: Why not build the check on the /abc/page.php and if that is invalid do a redirect.
No issues with redirects, easy to maintain, saver (everyone can set headers so not a secure idea)

Comment: <?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sid'])){ 
 header('Location:http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 

} else { 
 header('Location:http://localhost/abc/access_not_allowed.php'); 
}

Comment: Here it is, it will just check session and send back, but after it goes back the .htaccess should not return back to check.php

Comment: they have to be on seperate domain

Comment: Use some token to verify whether a request is checked or not. Referrer is not reliable as it can be disabled or hand-made on client side.

Comment: Any other solution with same method?

Comment: I have tested, referral page is shown empty when I used something like this RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/sec/gatekeeper.php?url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}-%{HTTP_REFERER} [R]

Comment: @Passerby, Please can you suggest what kind of token I can use, other then query string, or cookies?

Comment: @Kam On `page.php`, check if `$_GET["token"]` is set; if it's not, redirect to `check.php`; `check.php` then redirect back to `page.php?token=XXXXX`; on `page.php`, when `$_GET["token"]` captured, asked the other domain if that token is valid; if it is, proceed, if not, redirect back to `check.php`.

Comment: @Passerby thank you this seems helpful, let me do, thanks a lot :)